# How to pass no arguments in forwardRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a custom component using using `forwardRef()` and I use it multiple times
like this:

```
const CustomComp = React.forwardRef(({props...},{ref1,ref2})=>{...}); //this is in another file


const CombinedRef={ref1:useRef(),ref2:useRef()};

<CustomComp ref={CombinedRef}/>  //case 1
<CustomComp/>  //case 2
```

but there are occasions where the custom component doesn't need a `ref` like in the second case
but if I don't pass the `ref` in case 2 it gives an error

> null is not an object

so far my only solution has been `<CustomComp ref={{}}/> //case 2`
but is there a way where I don't have to pass ref in case 2 ?

Comment: The problem comes because you directly destructure your ref, this way it can't handle "undefined" anymore

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, even if I don't destructure like this `React.forwardRef(({props...},CombinedRef)=>{...})` it still gives and error, could you elaborate or post an answer?

Comment: there you go, i posted a full answer, could you accept it if it helps? thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot destructure your ref's directly if it should be an optional prop. So i shortly did a sandbox to show that... What you try right now is this:

```js
const CustomComp = forwardRef((props, { ref1, ref2 }) => {
  console.log("ref1", ref1);
  console.log("ref2", ref2);
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <span>CustomComp</span>
    </div>
  );
});
```

When you try to render that like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const ref1 = useRef();
  const ref2 = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomComp ref={{ ref1, ref2 }} />
      <CustomComp />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You get the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ref1' of 'object null' as it is null.`

But if you change it to this:

```js
const CustomComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { ref1, ref2 } = ref ? ref : {};
  console.log("ref1", ref1);
  console.log("ref2", ref2);
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <span>CustomComp</span>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Then it starts working ;-)

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-worker-pqjn3?file=/src/App.js:68-296